# Pc keeps restarting during rendering animation

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, error

I im trying to render a scene with 160 frames. But when i come back to check the progress after sometime i see that my pc has restarted. This has happened several times now for this same project. Ive never had this trouble before, i could leave my pc for however long time to let the render take place and come back after sometime.i dont see any error message either,it just simply restarts.I have pretty good specs too
GPU: rtx 3070
CPU: i7 12650h
RAM: 16gb
SSD: 1TB

Comment: I'm having the same problem.. did you find a solution? Thanks very much.

Comment: If you could add some more information, like Blender version and OS, that would make it easier to trouble-shoot.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you should be able to open Event Viewer to look at the system logs and determine the reason for shutdown.  Look at events during the time frame you believe the trouble occurred and find any critical entries.